# Show MessageBox if no records for report

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, crystal-reports

I already asked a Question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127572/change-visibility-of-object-when-report-has-no-data).

My this question is just a step ahead to same problem.

I have a delphi code which works perfectly for calling report.
But, now I wanted to show a MessageBox before opening rpt file.

I tried to query it separately for record count and then decide for MessageBox. But, this solution is having a worst case where a aprticular report's query itself takes 3 mins to execute and then again querying while opening rpt it takes 30 sec to load (in second query it takes less time may be because of some data may present in buffer/temp place,etc.).

```
qPODPhy.close;
qPODPhy.SQL.clear;
qPODPhy.SQL.text :='select * from ViewName';
qPODPhy.Open;

If qPODPhy.RecordCount < 1 Then
   MessageBOx('No data To Display...');
Else
Begin
   crRep.Somproperties := Initialization 
   .
   .
   .
   CrRep.SQLQuery := qPODPhy.SQL.text;
   crRep.action := 1 
End
```

My Question is :
How can I show a MessageBox if no record is going to present for particular view's output.
OR
Is there a method where I can open the dataset of .rpt file in delphi code and just check the count of records and make the decision? In short, is there some property of crystalreport component which can do this?

Comment: You can do a select count(*) separately, that is much faster. Or maybe select only one record if your DBMS supports it, whatever's fastest.

Comment: @JanDoggen, I think you should post your comment as answer (I'll upvote). I don't see any other alternatives in this case.

Comment: depending on the RDBMS you're using, you should use a stored procedure/or a view. This will decrease the time you wait.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a select count(*) separately, that is much faster.

Or maybe select only one record: SELECT TOP 1 ....

And, as [RBA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/368364/rba) suggested, you can try putting that SELECT COUNT in a stored procedure for even more speed.

Just experiments with these methods to see if/when you've gained enough speed.

Comment: I can use `Top 1` but its not helpful to me since there are only 3 records from view's output and that view takes 2.5 to 3 mins to execute. And the same view can't be modified.

Comment: Ah, it's the *view* that's slow. I see a lot of hits Googling for: view is slow sql server.     Maybe helpful? One of them is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492135/sql-view-running-slow

Comment: @Romesh, a 3 min execution time for a view usually means bad DB design. if you are joining tables make sure you have your indexes properly defined. surely that view could be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Are you pushing the data ? You can probably use ReadRecords method of the ReportDocument and check Rows.Count property. If the report is retrieving the data the you can use the NoData event of ReportDocument.

Comment: Your answer sounds good. I also thought about ReadRecords method. But its giving -1 before Action property is set. Is there any example or demo present? Please share the info